# Python and Exception Handling IOError

Tags: python, file, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to work with exception handling by displaying "No Such File" when the file doesn't exist.  I need to use a `try` statement.

```
import sys

try:
   f = open("h:\\nosuchdirectory\\nosuchfile.txt","w") # do not modify this line
    f.write("This is the grape file") # do not modify this line
    f.close() # do not modify this line

except IOError:
    print ("No Such File")
```

Started with:

```
f = open("h:\\nosuchdirectory\\nosuchfile.txt","w") # do not modify this line
f.write("This is the grape file") # do not modify this line
f.close() # do not modify this line
```

Comment: From the answer given by @RuslanOsipov, it appears that your code actually does not work. You should only post working code on Code Review, otherwise, your question will be deemed off-topic and closed. You can still edit your question with code working as intended (actually printing the message when the file does not exist) if you want to keep it open, and we will be happy to review it :)

Comment: Also, after re-reading a question this looks like an un-finished homework to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an interesting question.

@RuslanOsipov has provided a solution, but technically it is vulnerable to a time-of-check *vs.* time-of-use race condition.  In other words, there is a brief window between the `isfile()` call and the `open()` call where a things could go wrong.  Depending on the application, that could even be considered a security vulnerability.

So, what to do?  For the full story, read [Python Issue 12760](http://bugs.python.org/issue12760).  In [Python 3.3, `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open) gained an `'x'` mode flag that makes it behave like the code in this question wants it to.  For older versions of Python that lack the `'x'` flag, the [workaround](http://bugs.python.org/issue12760#msg147205) is:

```
def create(file):
    fd = os.open(file, os.O_EXCL | os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
    return os.fdopen(fd)
```

Comment: Ha, did not know that. Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You will not get `IOError` when opening a file for writing. Writing a non-existent file will just create a new one. Here's a solution:

```
import os

path = "h:\\nosuchdirectory\\nosuchfile.txt"
if os.path.isfile(path):
    print("No such file!")
    return
f = open(path, "w") # do not modify this line
f.write("This is the grape file") # do not modify this line
f.close() # do not modify this line
```

Comment: Good catch. I did not notice the `"w"`. That also means that the question is off-topic since the code does not work.

Comment: @Morwenn Oh, you're right. Voted.